# Insert value into CKEditor setting value using javaScript in GWT

Tags: javascript, string, gwt, ckeditor

With javascript I got my IFrame in UI. then `iframe.getContentDocument().getBody().setInnerText(val1);` to set value. But this cause to ignore the new line in text.

example : Here is a textArea multiline text.
String val1= "hello
              hello1";
but in ckeditor, It shows as : "hello hello1", It skip new line.
Am new with CKEditor, any help would be great.